# Magento 2, How to create API for customer forget password?

Tags: magento2.2, customer, api

Using `Magento`, `API`. I need to create an API for customer send `forget password`. I found the page that allows to customer send e-mail for request change `password` but I don't how to use this page for web service.

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php 
 require_once('baseurl.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 
$userData = array("username" => "", "password" => "");
$ch = curl_init($baseUrl . "rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));
$token = curl_exec($ch);

    $url=$baseUrl . "rest/V1/customers/password?email=".$emailId."&template=email_reset&websiteId=1";
    //echo $url;
     $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

     if($result=='true'){

        $response='{
            "status":"true",
            "message":"Password reset link has been sent to your email id"
        }';
        echo $response;
     }
     else{
        $response='{
                "status":"false",
                "message":"This email address is not registered"
            }';
                        echo $response;
    }
```

Comment: I am using this way for forget password api for mobile app

Comment: I got this message : `"message": "Too many password reset requests. Please wait and try again or contact %1.`

Comment: Set from store->configuration->customer->customer configuration->password option->Min Time Between Password Reset Requests

Comment: Try after 2 hours it will work

Answer (score 1):

### **webapi.xml**

```
<route url="/V1/customers/me/password" method="PUT">
    <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface" method="changePasswordById"/>
    <resources>
    <resource ref="self"/>
    </resources>
    <data>
        <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
    </data>
</route>
```

### **url :: action - PUT**

> http://127.0.0.1/magento.host/rest/V1/customers/me/password?customerId=160

### **Headers ::**

```
Authorization  Bearer <Admin Token>
Content-Type   application/json
```

**Body > raw > JSON(application/json) ::**

---

```
{
    "currentPassword": "aditya@123",
    "newPassword": "admin@123"
}
```

**Output**

> It will change customer password, need to pass current and new
>   password in body.